# Отображения имени пользователя в CentOS

Tags: bash, centos, root

Раньше писал команды от имени **[root@locallhost #dirname]**, после одной из перезагрузок логинюсь под *root'ом* и вижу, что я теперь не root, а **-bash-4.1#**. Все бы ничего, но ужасно не удобно не видеть текущую директорию, почему все стало так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмотреть переменную PS1 и переопределить ее. Для вашего случая
PS1="[\u@\h \W]#"
export  PS1

Comment: Я так понял эту команду надо вводить при каждом запуске?

Comment: почему? В профайле записать и все. В центосе, если стандартный bash, то в .bash_profile. Что то вроде PS1="текст"
export PS1

Comment: Прост опосле каждого перезапуска я -bash-4.1#

Comment: потому и в профайле. Там определяют, обычно, переменные  PS1="[\u@\h \W]#"; export PS1;